# Setting the form value when the form is initiated

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, init

I am trying to set a field value when a form is initiated.

The value of this field is retrieved when we enter the view - the view being the timesheet. Then for each Time set in the view, I want to relate it back to the timesheet.

```
@login_required
@requires_csrf_token
def timesheet(request, timesheet_id):
    timesheet = TimeSheet.objects.get(pk=timesheet_id)
    NewTimeFormSet = modelformset_factory(Time, form=TimeForm, formset=RequiredFormSet)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newtime_formset = NewTimeFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        for form in newtime_formset:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()  

    #then render template etc
```

So, to make sure the form validates I want to set this field when the form is initiated. When I try to set this field after POST in the view, I haven't been able to get the field to set or form to validate.

My code gets the timesheet_id when the model instance is initiated on entering the view

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # this allows it to get the timesheet_id
        print "initiating a timesheet"
        super(TimeSheet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then the form is generated and I run the form **init**. So this is what I've tried

```
class TimeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Time
        fields = ['project_id', 'date_worked', 'hours', 'description', 'timesheet_id',]

            # some labels and widgets, the timesheet_id has a hidden input

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "initiating form"
        super(TimeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        timesheet = TimeSheet.objects.get(id=timesheet_id)
        self.fields['timesheet_id'] = timesheet
```

This raises the error

> NameError: global name 'timesheet_id' is not defined

I don't know how to do this...

*I've also attempted setting the field in the form clean() method, but it populates (shown by a print) and then still doesn't validate and I raise a formset error 'This field is required'.*

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually accept a timesheet_id parameter in the form init method, so that value is not defined hence the error.

However, this is the wrong approach. There is no point passing a value to a form, outputting it as a hidden field, then getting it back, when you had it all along. The way to do this is to *exclude* the value from the form's fields, and set it on save.

```
class TimeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Time
        fields = ['project_id', 'date_worked', 'hours', 'description',]
```

...

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    newtime_formset = NewTimeFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if newtime_formset.is_valid():
        for form in newtime_formset:
            new_time = form.save(commit=False)
            new_time.timesheet_id = 1  #  or whatever
            new_time.save()
```

Note, again, you should check the validity of the whole formset before iterating through to save; otherwise you might end up saving some of them before encountering an invalid form.